# "position:absolute" usage in CSS

Tags: html, css

Consider an HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="outer"><div id="inner"></div></div>
    </body>
<html>
```

And its CSS:

```
#inner {
    height: 75px;
    width: 75px;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
#outer {
    height: 1500px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: green;
    position:static;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
```

From what I understand, the inner div should have a 20px left margin from the html element and not from the outer div as the outer div has a static position.
But it seems that the inner div always positions itself relative to outer div. What am I missing here?

If anyone can help, thanks.

**EDIT**:

Source: www.codecademy.com

Comment: `position: absolute` is positioned relative to the first non-static positioned element

Comment: An element with position: absolute; is positioned relative to the nearest positioned ancestor (instead of positioned relative to the viewport, like fixed).

However; if an absolute positioned element has no positioned ancestors, it uses the document body, and moves along with page scrolling.

add this code to your #inner  class:   left:0px;

Comment: *"From what I understand, the inner div should have a 20px left margin from the html element"* - what? That doesn't even make sense. suppose I have an element at the center of page, I add `margin-left: 20px;`, it should move 20px from the center, not from the edges of `<html>` element. Margin is not the property to use for absolutely position elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`position: absolute;` removes the element from normal flow and positions itself relative to the closest positioned ancestor. If none exist, it positions itself to the initial containing block, which takes the dimensions of the viewport. [Reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-positioning/#def-cb).

Nonetheless, for `absolute` elements, you should always specify the x and y dimensions (e.g., `top` and `left`), otherwise you may get some odd behavior, such as its positioning relative to a `static` ancestor element, which you are observing. See what happens when `top` and `left` are added:

```css
#inner {
  height: 75px;
  width: 75px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
#outer {
  height: 1500px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: green;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="outer">
    <div id="inner"></div>
  </div>
</body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The element is positioned relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element. Thus the inner div will position itself based on the parent element containing it, in this case the "outer" div.